# Trying to understand kotlin code given below

Tags: android, kotlin

This code related to search in calendar app, but I can't really understand how does it work. 
Can anyone help me?

```
    private fun searchQueryChanged(text: String) {
    mLatestSearchQuery = text
    search_placeholder_2.beGoneIf(text.length >= 3)
    if (text.length >= 3) {
        eventsHelper.getEventsWithSearchQuery(text, this) { searchedText, events ->
            if (searchedText == mLatestSearchQuery) {
                search_results_list.beVisibleIf(events.isNotEmpty())
                search_placeholder.beVisibleIf(events.isEmpty())
                val listItems = getEventListItems(events)
                val eventsAdapter = EventListAdapter(this, listItems, true, this, search_results_list) {
                    if (it is ListEvent) {
                        Intent(applicationContext, EventActivity::class.java).apply {
                            putExtra(EVENT_ID, it.id)
                            startActivity(this)
                        }
                    }
                }

                search_results_list.adapter = eventsAdapter
            }
        }
    } else {
        search_placeholder.beVisible()
        search_results_list.beGone()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information here?  What environment is this code from?

Comment: It's from Android Studio 3.6.1
I assume this function regulates search query bar, just makes it a bit more interactive by using .beVisible .beGone options and also doing search through calendar events. That's the guess.

Comment: Sorry, completely glossed over the android tag.  It's been ages since I have done any android dev and never used Kotlin there.  I don't know the latest APIs and this doesn't look familiar.